# Crawling web pages with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

I have a seed file of 250 URLs of IMDB's top 250 movies.

I need to crawl each one of them and get some info from it.
I've created a function that gets a URL of a movie and returns the info I need. It works great. My problem is when I'm trying to run this function on all of the 250 URLs.
After a certian amount (not constant!) of URLs that were crawled successfully, the program stops its run. The python.exe process takes 0% CPU and the memory consumption doesn't change. After some debugging, I figured that the problem is with the parsing, it just stops working and I have no idea why (stuck on a find command).

I'm using urllib2 to get the HTML content of the URL, than parse it as a string and then continue to the next URL (I'm going only once on each of these strings, linear time for all the checks and extractions).

Any idea what can cause this kind of behavior?

EDIT:

I'm attaching one of the problematic functions' code (got 1 more, but I'm guessing it's the same problem)

```
def getActors(html,actorsDictionary):

    counter = 0
    actorsLeft = 3
    actorFlag = 0
    imdbURL = "http://www.imdb.com"

    for line in html:        
        # we have 3 actors, stop
        if (actorsLeft == 0):
            break

        # current line contains actor information
        if (actorFlag == 1):
            endTag = str(line).find('/"    >')
            endTagA = str(line).find('</a>')

            if (actorsLeft == 3):
                actorList = str(line)[endTag+7:endTagA]
            else:
                actorList += "&#44; " + str(line)[endTag+7:endTagA]

            actorURL = imdbURL + str(line)[str(line).find('href=')+6:endTag]
            actorFlag = 0
            actorsLeft -= 1
            actorsDictionary[actorURL] = str(line)[endTag+7:endTagA]

        # check if next line contains actor information
        if (str(line).find('<td class="name">') > -1 ):
            actorFlag = 1

    # convert commas and clean \n
    actorList = actorList.replace(",","&#44; ")
    actorList = actorList.replace("\n","") 

    return actorList
```

I'm calling the function this way:

```
for url in seedFile:
    moviePage = urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
    print(getTitleAndYear(moviePage),",",movieURL,",",getPlot(moviePage),getActors(moviePage,actorsDictionary))
```

This works great without the getActors function

There is no exception raised here (I removed the try and catch for now)
and it's getting stuck in the for loop after some iterations

EDIT 2: if I run only the getActors function, it works well and finishes all the URLs in the seed file (250)

Comment: How large is the function?  Can you post it, or a scaled down version of it?  Also have you tried debugging it(attaching pdb)?

Comment: What's the find command it is stuck on?  And how is it stuck?  Just spinning, or does it raise an exception?

Comment: As an aside, you may find it interesting to note that the entire IMDb database is available for download here: http://www.imdb.com/interfaces rather than trying to scrape their web interface.

Comment: I attached some of the code. And I can't use the imdb DB, this is a college project... :)

Comment: Indentation of line `if (str(line).find('<td class="name">') > -1 ):
` looks wrong. Did you brake it during c&p or is that how it looks in your code?

Comment: it doesn't look like that, don't know why it came up like this here. it's aligned with the comment above it (so it's included in the for loop)